# avoid matrix inverse warning in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm working with 6x6 matrices which have varying precisions of data. When I try to inverse that matrix in MATLAB I usually get `Inf` or `NaN` as all the data and MATLAB throws a warning:

> Matrix is singular to working precision.

Is there anyway to avoid it and get proper results?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: hmm... its matrix inverse using matlab and im using the inv function. I dont think it to be a "pure" mathematical question

Comment: Matlab `inv` is no magic. It only works when linear-algebra permits/allows for inversion. You get this error because you are trying to do something that is **mathematically** undefined. You should seek counsel with numerical analysis people that can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Singular matrix mean that determinant of that is zero. For computing inverse the determinant must be different from zero. My advise is to read some elementary book of algebra before using some application for computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix seems to be rank deficient. Only full rank matrices can be robustly inverted.
You may circumvent your problem by adding a small identity matrix to the original one.

```
 A = rand(6,5);
 A = A*A'; %' symmetric rank 5 matrix
 iA = inv(A); % results with NaNs and infs A is singular
 iAs = inv( A + eye(6)*1e-3 ); % add small (1e-3) elements to diagonal - this should help
```

Comment: is there any way to determine which value should be added to diagonal elements?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - this is exactly a question for math.stackexchange.com